# Using my own .csv in tensorflow

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow

I asked a previous question about the same code here [where and how to put the filename in this tensorflow code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41604666/where-and-how-to-put-the-filename-in-this-tensorflow-code/41604790?noredirect=1#comment70413582_41604790)

Not sure if I should merge that into this question or leave it as is.

The following code is from Sirajology's git hub. I have not found a super straight forward tutorial on how to get one's own .csv file into a simple tensorflow neural network so my hope is this thread might provide that instruction for future searchers.

The code is as follows

```
import tensorflow.python.platform

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Global variables.
NUM_LABELS = 2    # The number of labels.
BATCH_SIZE = 5  # The number of training examples to use per training step.

# Define the flags useable from the command line.
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('train', None,
                           'File containing the training data (labels & features).')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('test', None,
                           'File containing the test data (labels & features).')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('num_epochs', 1,
                            'Number of examples to separate from the training '
                            'data for the validation set.')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_boolean('verbose', False, 'Produce verbose output.')
FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

# Extract numpy representations of the labels and features given rows consisting of:
#   label, feat_0, feat_1, ..., feat_n
def extract_data(filename):

    # Arrays to hold the labels and feature vectors.
    labels = []
    fvecs = []

    # Iterate over the rows, splitting the label from the features. Convert labels
    # to integers and features to floats.
    for line in file(filename):
        row = line.split(",")
        labels.append(int(row[0]))
        fvecs.append([float(x) for x in row[1:]])

    # Convert the array of float arrays into a numpy float matrix.
    fvecs_np = np.matrix(fvecs).astype(np.float32)

    # Convert the array of int labels into a numpy array.
    labels_np = np.array(labels).astype(dtype=np.uint8)

    # Convert the int numpy array into a one-hot matrix.
    labels_onehot = (np.arange(NUM_LABELS) == labels_np[:, None]).astype(np.float32)

    # Return a pair of the feature matrix and the one-hot label matrix.
    return fvecs_np,labels_onehot

def main(argv=None):
    # Be verbose?
    verbose = FLAGS.verbose

    # Get the data.
    train_data_filename = FLAGS.train
    test_data_filename = FLAGS.test

    # Extract it into numpy matrices.
    train_data,train_labels = extract_data(train_data_filename)
    test_data, test_labels = extract_data(test_data_filename)

    # Get the shape of the training data.
    train_size,num_features = train_data.shape

    # Get the number of epochs for training.
    num_epochs = FLAGS.num_epochs

    # This is where training samples and labels are fed to the graph.
    # These placeholder nodes will be fed a batch of training data at each
    # training step using the {feed_dict} argument to the Run() call below.
    x = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, num_features])
    y_ = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, NUM_LABELS])

    # For the test data, hold the entire dataset in one constant node.
    test_data_node = tf.constant(test_data)

    # Define and initialize the network.

    # These are the weights that inform how much each feature contributes to
    # the classification.
    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_features,NUM_LABELS]))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([NUM_LABELS]))
    y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W) + b)

    # Optimization.
    cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y))
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cross_entropy)

    # Evaluation.
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))

    # Create a local session to run this computation.
    with tf.Session() as s:
        # Run all the initializers to prepare the trainable parameters.
        tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
        if verbose:
            print ('Initialized!')
            print
            print ('Training.')

        # Iterate and train.
        for step in xrange(num_epochs * train_size // BATCH_SIZE):
            if verbose:
                print (step,)

            offset = (step * BATCH_SIZE) % train_size
            batch_data = train_data[offset:(offset + BATCH_SIZE), :]
            batch_labels = train_labels[offset:(offset + BATCH_SIZE)]
            train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch_data, y_: batch_labels})

            if verbose and offset >= train_size-BATCH_SIZE:
                print

        # Give very detailed output.
        if verbose:
            print
            print ('Weight matrix.')
            print (s.run(W))
            print
            print ('Bias vector.')
            print (s.run(b))
            print
            print ("Applying model to first test instance.")
            first = test_data[:1]
            print ("Point =", first)
            print ("Wx+b = ", s.run(tf.matmul(first,W)+b))
            print ("softmax(Wx+b) = ", s.run(tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(first,W)+b)))
            print

        print ("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: test_data, y_: test_labels}))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

When I run the code from terminal with the following command (windows10 cmd line) `python YourScript.py --train FileName.csv --test TestName.csv --num_epochs 5 --verbose True` I get these errors. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Error #1**
  File "softmax.py", line 133, in 
    tf.app.run()

```
tf.app.run()
```

**Error #2**
 File "C:\app.py", line 43, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))

```
labels_onehot = (np.arange(NUM_LABELS) == labels_np[:, None]).astype(np.float32)
```

**Error #3**
 File "softmax.py", line 57, in main
    train_data,train_labels = extract_data(train_data_filename)

```
train_data,train_labels = extract_data(train_data_filename) 
test_data, test_labels = extract_data(test_data_filename)
```

**Error #4** 
 File "softmax.py", line 31, in extract_data
    for line in file(filename):
NameError: name 'file' is not defined

```
for line in file(filename):
        row = line.split(",")
        labels.append(int(row[7]))
        fvecs.append([float(x) for x in row[1:6]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem stems from this line, which uses a built-in function (`file()`) that is not available in Python 3.5:

```
for line in file(filename):
```

Replacing it with the following line should fix the error:

```
for line in open(filename):
```

Comment: Hallelujah! Thank you so much. This stuff is a real journey for those of us who are new to programming.  Also, I changed xrange to range...